# Android Studio "exception: Gradle task assembledebug failed with exit code 1"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I need to use flutter to develop a project, but I'm new to this flutter and Android Studio stuff. After turning on my virtual Android device, I wanted to run the code to test it, but I got exception: Gradle task assembledebug failed with exit code 1 error. What is the reason of this? When I run the flutter doctor command from CMD, it doesn't show Android Studio as existing, could it be because of that? Even so, I don't understand why Android Studio isn't already installed. I would be glad if you can help.

**This is the error I get:**
[image]

**When I run the Flutter doctor command, it shows like this:**

```
    `C:\Users\USER>flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale tr-TR)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [!] Android Studio
        X android-studio-dir = /home/piotr/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.6858069
        X Android Studio not found at /home/piotr/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.6858069
    [√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    [√] Connected device (3 available)
    
    ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by installing jdk. Those who get the same error can install jdk and try. It will most likely be resolved.